# Java: Multidimensional Scaling?

Tags: java, nlp, multi-dimensional-scaling

I'm doing a Natural Language Processing project where I compute a bunch of attributes of a text, giving me a vector of values for each text. I want to compare these vectors with multidimensional scaling. What Java libraries/toolkits do you recommend for doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the following MDSJ to reduce a matrix from k dimensions to n  dimensions. Where k was 4000 and n was 3 in my case. The app runs both as a standalone application and as a jar lib that can be included in your application.

http://www.inf.uni-konstanz.de/algo/software/mdsj/

Answer (score 0):

Try the following post, it may provide what you are looking for.

[Java Scientific Packages similar to SciPy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/482305/java-scientific-packages-similar-to-scipy)